# Finding a certain character from lines of input

Tags: c++, string, input

I am currently trying to solve this kattis problem in C++:

[Ecape Wall Maria](https://open.kattis.com/problems/escapewallmaria)

> Wall Maria has been broken! Eren must evacuate as soon as possible from his house. He must find the fastest route to escape within Wall Maria before the titans rush in. Wall Maria is represented as a N×M grid in which Eren can move horizontally or vertically.
>
> There are burning houses and buildings which prevent Eren from passing through them. The burning houses and buildings are represented as ‘1’. Unburned or safe areas are represented as ‘0’. There are some areas which can be entered but only from a specific direction. These areas can be represented by either ‘U’, ‘D’, ‘L’, or ‘R’. For example, if there is an ‘R’ that means that area can only be entered from the right neighboring tile within Wall Maria’s grid. Similarly, ‘U’ tiles can only be entered from above, ‘D’ tiles can only be entered from below, and ‘L’ tiles can only be entered from the left.
>
> Eren knows the time t at which the titans will rush in. It takes 1 unit of time to traverse 1 zone (which corresponds to 1 tile in the grid). Once he reaches any border of Wall Maria he is safe.
>
> Eren’s starting position is represented by the letter ‘S’. If Eren escapes at or before time t, he is safe. Given his position within Wall Maria determine if it is possible to escape. If it is possible determine the number of zones that must be traversed to lead to the quickest escape.
>
> Input
> The input consists of a single test case. The first line contains three integers t (1≤t≤200) , N (1≤N≤100) and M (1≤M≤100). The rest of N lines will be Wall Maria’s grid containing characters ‘1‘, ‘0‘, ‘S‘, ‘U‘, ‘D‘, ‘L‘, or ‘R‘. There is exactly one ‘S‘ in the input.
>
> Output
> If it is possible to escape Wall Maria, output the minimum number of zones that must be traversed to escape. If it is not possible to escape, print “NOT POSSIBLE”!

I am having some issues with finding the character "S" in the matrix on input.

I am thinking that once we have the input of the matrix, we find the character "S" and then look to the right, left, up and down of that character. If the character is not = 1 then you repeat the process from that character until you have "left" the matrix.

However, I have tried writing code to look for the starting point (the character "S) but I have been unsuccessful in doing that.

Furthermore, I am not sure how to look around the character once I have found it. I have only gotten to the point where I can accept input, not much further. Help would be appreciated
This is my code so far:

```
int main(){
    int M;
    int N;
    int t;
    string wall;
    cin >> t >> N >> M;
    //Takes the matrix input
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cin >> wall;
    }
}
```

Comment: `string` is not the correct datatype. Probably `vector<vector<char>>`

Comment: FYI, your code is always replacing the same string, `wall`, in each iteration of your loop.  You may want to search `wall` after you input it, e.g. `if (wall.find('S') != std::string::npos)`

Answer (score 0):

The two steps are:

1. Decide what data structure you want to use to represent the grid you're about to traverse. `std::vector<std::string>` is a standard choice here.
2. Read the grid into the vector line by line, storing the row and column for `'S'` as you go.

Here's one approach:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int M;
    int N;
    int t;
    int sx = 0;
    int sy = 0;
    std::cin >> t >> N >> M;
    std::vector<std::string> grid(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        std::cin >> grid[i];
        size_t pos = grid[i].find("S");

        if (pos != std::string::npos) {
            sx = pos;
            sy = i;
        }
    }

    // show the position; remove when you're ready to solve the problem
    std::cout << sx << ", " << sy << "\n";
}
```

Here's the output on two of the samples:

```
$ ./a
1 4 4
1S01
1001
1011
0U11
1, 0
$ ./a
2 4 4
1111
1S01
1011
0U11
1, 1
```